# Adding symlink to scripts into rc<number>.d folders to start process during system startup

Tags: linux, startup, fedora, init, rc

I am using fedora 15.

I am trying to add MYSql daemon to start during system strtup.

I have understood that I will have to add it to `rc5.d` as it is the default target & is `graphical.target`.

from `inittab`:

> systemd uses 'targets' instead of runlevels. By default, there are two main targets:
>
> multi-user.target: analogous to runlevel 3
>    graphical.target: analogous to runlevel 5

From [An introduction to services, runlevels, and rc.d scripts](https://www.linux.com/news/enterprise/systems-management/8116-an-introduction-to-services-runlevels-and-rcd-scripts) :

> When the system is shut down, there is another symlink in the /etc/rc0.d and /etc/rc6.d directories (halt and reboot, respectively) that starts with a K instead of an S, which tells init to shut down the process.

I notice that symlink to `httpd` are present in all the `rc<number>.d` folders 
as symlink: *`K15httpd -> ../init.d/httpd`*.
No symlink is present that starts with *`S`*. Makes sense as I have to start it manually.

> - Why is the symlink *`K15httpd -> ../init.d/httpd`* present in all the *`rc<number>.d`* folders?
> - What should I name the symlink if I want to start *httpd* during system startup?
> - What is the number that is present in the symlink? i.e. *K15httpd -> ../init.d/httpd* what is *15* here?
> - I read ([here](http://forums.devshed.com/mysql-help-4/how-to-start-mysql-at-boot-time-in-linux-2267.html)) that the symlink to *MYSql* should be *S98mysql* is it right and what should the name to symlink that starts with *K* should be?

Comment: [chkconfig](http://linux.die.net/man/8/chkconfig)

Comment: And *how* is this programming related?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The naming convention for the RC scripts is as follows for any  in `/etc/init.d`

- Start scripts `S##<base script name>`
- Kill scripts `K##<base script name>`

The `##` represent the order in which the script will be executed during the run of runlevel control script.  The order in which the scripts are executed is:

- Kill scripts
- Start Scripts

The order in which it will be execute is the same as the order of files in the output of:

```
`ls /etc/rc#.d/K*`
`ls /etc/rc#.d/S*`
```

So by this token the existence of `K15httpd` script implies that at this runlevel in your case `5` the apache(or another web service) should be stopped.

By same token the kill script for `MySQL` in lower levels then the one you start it in would be `K02MySQL`.

You can look at [this link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-write-sys-v-init-script-to-start-stop-service.html) to read about the writing the System V init scripts.