# How to run a program on startup in Debian

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, debian, startup

I am attempting to run a program that I made on startup on my Raberry Pi 2. It is running Debian (Jessie) but it doesn't seem to work. I tried following this guide: [Debian: Running Scripts on StartUp](https://www.debian-administration.org/article/28/Making_scripts_run_at_boot_time_with_Debian) and creating a system link but nothing seems to be working. The program works when I run it not on startup. Here's the code:

```
#!/bin/sh
#/etc/init.d/StartGRIP.sh
#

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:            StartGRIP.sh
# Required-Start:      $local_fs $network
# Required-Stop:       $local_fs
# Default-Start:       2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:        0 1 6
# Short-Description:   Starts GRIP Pipeline
# Description:         During startup, runs below command and starts GRIP
### END INIT INFO
# Start processing
env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/pi/vision/grip:LD_LIBRARY_PATH java -jar...
```

The last command works so I didn't include the whole line as it is a long line.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: you can use [`update-rc.d`](http://www.debianadmin.com/manpages/updatercmanpage.htm) to generate the symlinks to the appropriate run levels (this assumes Sys V init), but with Systemd the whole process is different, see this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47695/how-to-write-startup-script-for-systemd) for how to write systemd start up scripts

Comment: I've used that command, and it still doesn't work. I even tried creating one via `ls`

Comment: how did you use the command? if you don't specify the correct run level it will not start, also if the app depends on other things to start you have to ensure the dependencies start before it

Comment: Link to the guide I followed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8837680/adding-symlink-to-scripts-into-rcnumber-d-folders-to-start-process-during-syst

Comment: I linked it to rc2.d

Comment: Surely the second LD_LIBRARY_PATH on the last line needs a dollar sign in front of it?

Comment: you should have the script in `/etc/init.d/`, so let's assume your script is `/etc/init.d/StartGRIP.sh` all you need to run is `sudo update-rc.d StartGRIP.sh defaults`

Comment: I have done that a lot, doesn't work :/

Comment: To create a symlink, use the 'ln' command, not 'ls'.

Answer (score 3):

Create a desktop entry for the program and place it in `~/.config/autostart`

As an example that starts Safe Eyes program placing it as `~/.config/autostart/safeeyes.desktop`.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=0.9.4
Type=Application
Name=Safe Eyes
Comment=Protect your eyes from eye strain
Exec=safeeyes
OnlyShowIn=XFCE;
StartupNotify=false
Terminal=false
Hidden=false
Categories=Utility;
```

[Optional] Set the proper permission.

```
  sudo chmod 644 /.config/autostart/[program-name].desktop
```

Comment: is it possible to use this method for a script that requieres sudo privileges?

Comment: @GabrielSandoval Yes it's possible.

Comment: This runs the program when you log in to your desktop, not when the computer boots.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative way:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

And add

```
@reboot file_you_want_to_run &
```

Comment: Not sure why but, this is unreliable, however, works most of the time. Not sure at what runlevel this is executed.

Comment: There is no need to run the script in the background. `cron` by definition runs asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

Tested on Debian 12

```
Gnome Desktop >Applications > Utilities > Tweaks > Startup Applications > Add
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to start, but you can use a systemd service as user for this too by specifying the directives `User=` and `Group=` in the `[Service]` section of the unit file.. I think this might be the cleanest option. Example:

```
/etc/systemd/system/mytool.service

[Unit]
Description=mytool

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/mytool -arg1 -arg2
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/mytool -stop
Restart=on-failure
User=myuser
Group=myusersgroup
```

If you are using a tiling window manager like i3 you can also use this:

```
~/.config/i3/config:
exec --no-startup-id i3-msg '/usr/bin/mytool -arg1'
```